# How many ways to arrange the word?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to arrange "RACECAR" such that the word you make starts with "ACE"

Counting "ACE" as one part, we get there are $$\frac{5!}{2!} = 5*4*3 = 60$$

ways to arrange "RACECAR" so that "ACE" is together.

Is this correct?

Comment: The question says "starts with ACE", not "contains ACE".

Answer (score 1):

since letters 'ACE' are fixed in beginning so the remaining letters A, C, R, R can be arranged by $4!/2!=12$

Answer (score 0):

Put $ACE$ at the beginning, then count the number of ways to arrange $\color\red{A}\color\green{C}\color\orange{RR}$:

$$\frac{(\color\red1+\color\green1+\color\orange2)!}{\color\red1!\times\color\green1!\times\color\orange2!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Words start with ACE. So ACE is fix. It should be done in only 1 way.

Remaining alphabets are RACR.

Now we have total 4 alphabets so 4 alphabets can be arrange in 4! ways.

Total ways = 1 × 4!

But R is repeating 2 times. So divide total ways by 2!

Total ways = $\frac{1 × 4!}{2!}$

= $\frac{1 × 4 × 3 × 2!}{2!}$

= 1 × 4 × 3 = 12